# AWS Data Exchange Limits how to avoid?

Tags: amazon-web-services

If a data source has more than 100 files of a dataset, for example, 1000 files per revision?
What is the best way to import all of them?

["A single job can import or export up to 100 assets to or from Amazon S3"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/data-exchange/latest/userguide/limits.html)